# P4 edit can cause whitespace without edit?

Tags: java, whitespace, perforce

I have a tool what uses Perforce. When it merge a branch back to the parent, mark the project branch with checkout a text file, and submit it **unchanged**. This tool also use that text file, for read the actual build number. My problem is, a "/n" appeared in the text, and because it have to contain just numbers, it's a big problem.

Have anyone met this problem, or this can't caused by P4C?

Maybe important, I don't use P4JAVA here.

Please note that I'm debugging right now, and I'm not sure the problem is here, but at the moment this seems the most probable.

```
//<path> is a legit path, I just shortened the code here
commandSync = "p4 -d " + getPerforceRoot() + " sync " + selectedDataBean.getP4Path() + "<path>/BuildNum.txt";
        CommandResultBean syncCommandResult = commandExecuter.runAndGetResults(commandSync);
//command executer that runs the command string in cmd

commandMark = "p4 -d " + getPerforceRoot() + " edit  -c " + changelistNumber + " " + selectedDataBean.getP4Path() + "<path>/BuildNum.txt";
        CommandResultBean markCommandResult = commandExecuter.runAndGetResults(commandMark);

commandSubmit = "p4 -d " + getPerforceRoot() + " submit -f submitunchanged -c " + changelistNumber;
        CommandResultBean submitCommandResult = commandExecuter.runAndGetResults(commandSubmit);
```

Comment: I assume you mean that `\n` (a newline) is appended to your file?  Are you certain that the file wasn't originally terminated with a newline (which is common)?  If all else fails, you could try checking in the file as a `binary` type.  However, I'm unable to reproduce your problem even with files checked in as `text`, regardless of what I change my client's `LineEnd` setting to.

Comment: I can't even reproduce. I asked this because I wanted to be sure about this one can't be the problem ( I'm pretty sure it can't be normally). By the way I though that I/O operations don't take the `\n` to the String this way. So `Integer.parseInt()` can deal with it, but I was wrong.

Comment: If you control the tool parsing the file, you should just make it trim whitespace.

Comment: Can you doublecheck if you submitted the BuildNum.txt file from p4clients with different LineEnd settings?